# (AutoCAD) How to change font style for multiple items at once?

Tags: autocad

I have the following problem.

I have pulled some labels from QGIS to AutoCAD LT with the following settings (image below).

[image]

I want to have the font bold. Unfortunately, the AutoCAD LT doesn't render it this way treating the letters like vector layers instead of the font style.
I tried to change the font by using the Select Similar option and Properties -> Font

[image]

even if I change the font style it doesn't change after applying it. The same problem occurs when create completely new font style and assign it to all items in properties.

I can change it by double-clicking on every single feature, but it's not available for all of them in one go. Having it applied would significantly accelerate the job, as I have 368 in total.

Is there any chance to trigger the font changes?

Comment: Did you try "REGEN ALL" after changing the text style?  After setting one label the way you want, have your tried the match properties paintbrush?

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to keep our labels in TEXT format instead of MTEXT. In QGIS, we can export our DXF project by switching off the **Export labels as MTEXT elements**.

[image]